# Get screenshot of current foreground app on Android having root priviliges

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-view, android-screen-support

I'm developing an application that **is installed on the system partition** and I would like to know if it's possible to get a screenshot of the current foreground application from a service. Of course, the application being any third party app.

I'm not interested in security issues or anything related to that matter. I only want to get a snapshot of the current foreground third party app.

Note: I'm aware of the `/system/bin/screencap` solution but I'm looking for a more elegant alternative that does everything programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months have passed since I asked this question but just now had the time to add this feature. The way to do this is simply by calling `screencap -p <file_name_absolute_path>` and then grabbing the file. Next is the code I used:

```
private class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, File> {
    @Override
    protected File doInBackground(String... params) {
        File screenshotFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), SCREENSHOT_FILE_NAME);
        try {
            Process screencap = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p " + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath());
            screencap.waitFor();
            return screenshotFile;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(File screenshot_file) {
        // Do something with the file.
    }
}
```

Remember to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" />` permission to the manifest. Otherwise screenshot.png will be blank.

This is much simpler than what Goran stated and is what I finally used.

Note: It only worked for me when the app is installed on the system partition.

Comment: Does this require the phone to be rooted or plugged in via USB?

Comment: @CamHart I think it does require root but don't remember for sure. You could try it. It has nothing to do with the USB plug, though.

Answer (score 2):

The method that I'm going to describe below will let you to programmatically take screen shots of whatever app it's in the foreground from a background process.

I am assuming that you have a rooted device.
I this case you can use the [uiautomator framework](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) to get the job done.

This framework has a been created to automate black box testing of apps on android, but it will suite this purpose as well.
We are going to use the method

[`takeScreenshot(File storePath, float scale, int quality)`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#takeScreenshot(java.io.File,%20float,%20int))

This goes in the service class:

```
File f = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir, "test.jar");

//this command will start uiautomator
String cmd = String.format("uiautomator runtest %s -c com.mypacket.Test", f.getAbsoluteFile());
Process p = doCmds(cmd);
if(null != p)
{
    p.waitFor();
}
else
{
    Log.e(TAG, "starting the test FAILED");
}

private Process doCmds(String cmds)
{
    try
    {
        Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes(cmds + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        return su;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "doCmds FAILED");

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the class for uiautomator:

```
public class Test extends UiAutomatorTestCase
{
    public void testDemo()
    {
        UiDevice dev = UiDevice.getInstance();

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        dev.takeScreenshot(f, 1.0, 100);
    }
}
```

It's best if you create a background thread in which uiautomator will run, that way it will not run onto the ui thread. (the Service runs on the ui thread).

uiatuomator doesn't know about or have a android context.
Once uiautomator gets the control you will be able to call inside it android methods that do not take a context parameter or belong to the context class.

If you need to communicate between uiautomator and the service (or other android components) you can use [LocalSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html).
This will allow communication in both ways.